# JQuery Datepicker not updating my var correctly when a date a chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-framework

I can't seem for the life of me to get this to work properly.

When the jQuery is executed, it works fine and sets the var (text) just fine the first time.

Then, if its called again, it keeps the original text and does not change, unless of course, I were to refresh the webpage.

How can the code be modified, such that the var text is set to what it is supposed to be?

```
var sdate, text

//....1)
        $(document).on('keypress', function (e){ if(e.which === 13 && $('#dd').dialog('isOpen') === true) { $('.ui-state-active').click(); } }); 
        $('#dd').dialog({ autoOpen: true, modal: true, overlay: { opacity: 1.0, background: 'black' }, title: "SELECT A NEW DUE DATE", height: 235, width: 235, draggable: false, resizable: false});

        $('#d1').datepicker({
            onSelect: function() {

                sdate = $(this).val();

                text = 'THIS IS THE ORIGINAL TEXT WHEN A DATE IS SELECTED IN THE DATEPICKER'

                $("#dd").dialog("close");

             }//end of onSelect: function() {
        });//end of datepicker


//....2)
        $(document).on('keypress', function (e){ if(e.which === 13 && $('#dd').dialog('isOpen') === true) { $('.ui-state-active').click(); } }); 
        $('#dd').dialog({ autoOpen: true, modal: true, overlay: { opacity: 1.0, background: 'black' }, title: "SELECT APPROVAL DATE", height: 235, width: 235, draggable: false, resizable: false});

        $('#d1').datepicker({
            onSelect: function() {

                sdate = $(this).val();

                text = 'THE TEXT NEVER CHANGES FOR SOME ODD REASON AND CANT SEEM TO FIGURE OUT WHY'

                $("#dd").dialog("close");

             }//end of onSelect: function() {
        });//end of datepicker
```

Comment: There's a syntax error due to an apostrophe in the second text assignment. Noticed thanks to the Stack Overflow syntax highlighter.

Comment: fixed it, but the var text still never changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `datepicker` on the same HTML element (i assume an input) twice. The onSelect from the 2nd bit of code will never run. see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChUc3/)

What you would need to do is have a 2nd `<input>` tag which is also a datepicker, OR come up with another way.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the same id twice (#d1) ... the second datepicker should reference the second text box. Quick fix. Perhaps a copy and paste leftover.